# Two processors can't log the information at the same time by using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I have two projects A and B, both of them use a NLog libiary. Now I have an issue:

**if A writes loginfo into the log file first, then the B never logs. And if B writes loginfo into the log file first, then A never logs.**

As A and B use a same NLog libiary, so they use the same Nlog Config, but they will be built in two processors, here is the config info.

Does somebody have any good idea on this issue?

```
//Set NLog Config by:
//https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API
private static Logger GenerateLogInstance()
{
    // Step 1. Create configuration object 
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    // Step 2. Create targets
    var fileTarget = new FileTarget()
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Logs\${shortdate}.log",
        Layout = @"${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"

    };
    //var wrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper(fileTarget, 5000, AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Discard);

    // Step 3. Define rules
    config.AddTarget("myprojectLog", fileTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget));
    // Step 4. Activate the configuration
    var factory = new LogFactory(config);

    return factory.GetLogger("myprojectLog");
}
```

Comment: Your question starts out as "processor" suggesting threads, but actually it sounds like 2 apps. 2 apps not writing to the same file sounds likely, as it probably opens the file with locks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use *nlog* but take a look at the following. You may need to set `concurrentWrites="true"`

[File target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target)

> concurrentWrites - Enables support for optimized concurrent writes to
>   same log file from multiple processes on the same machine-host, when
>   using keepFileOpen = true. By using a special technique that lets it
>   keep the files open from multiple processes. If only single process
>   (and single AppDomain) application is logging, then it is faster to
>   set to concurrentWrites = False. Boolean Default: True. Note: in UWP
>   this setting should be false

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I checked the NLog, concurrentWrites default value is true :(

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this instead:

```
private static LogFactory GenerateLogFactory()
{
    // Step 0. Create isolated LogFactory
    var logFactory = new LogFactory();
    // Step 1. Create configuration object 
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration(logFactory);
    // Step 2. Create targets
    var fileTarget = new FileTarget()
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Logs\${shortdate}.log",
        Layout = @"${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"
    };
    // Step 3. Define rules
    config.AddTarget("myprojectLog", fileTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget));
    // Step 4. Activate the configuration
    logFactory.Configuration = config;
    return logFactory;
}

private static Logger GenerateLogInstance()
{
    return GenerateLogFactory().GetLogger("myprojectLog");
}
```

Btw. if two projects in the same solution is using this same method, then you can consider doing this:

```
Lazy<LogFactory> LazyLogFactory = new Lazy<LogFactory>(() => GenerateLogFactory());

private static Logger GenerateLogInstance(string loggerName = "myprojectLog")
{
    return LazyLogFactory.Value.GetLogger(loggerName);
}
```